# How to get all index of dynamic div in click button show more jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, dom

I have categories .In each category I have custom posts. At initaillay, we displayed 2 posts for every category. In the category we have more than 2 posts add button show more .In click button show more, we display posts by 4. The two initial posts + 4 posts .In every click show more we display by 4 posts.At now , we display only one post .It'is the first index .this is the problem .We should display all the other posts for category.

[image]

```
<?php
        $custom_terms = get_terms('genre');

        foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
            wp_reset_query();
            $postsPerPage = -1;
            $current_category = "";

            $args = [
                'post_type' => 'film',
                'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                'orderby' => 'id',
                'order' => 'ASC',


                'tax_query' => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $custom_term->slug,

                    ],
                ],
            ];

            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            $parent_included = false;
            if ($loop->have_posts()) {
                              echo '<h2 class="text-actualites">' . $custom_term->name . '</h2>';

                $counter = 0;
                //$count_posts = count($loop->have_posts());
                $i = 0;

                while ($loop->have_posts()) :

                    $loop->the_post();

                    $i++;

                    $img = get_field('image', "$post->ID");

                    $cat = $custom_term->term_id;
                    $current_category = $cat;

                    if ($custom_term->name == "Adventure") {
                    ?>

                     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                         <div class="card1 recrutements">
                             <div class="card-header">
                                 <div>
                                     <img src=<?php echo $img["url"]; ?> class='mymap-icon' alt=''>

                                 </div>


                                 <div>
                                     <span class="titre-recrutement">
                                         <div class="bnt-makers ">Communiqué de presse </div>
                                         <div> <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>


                                         <div class="bnt-maker "><?php the_field('nom', $post->ID); ?>
                                         </div>

                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="card-body">
                                 <p><?php the_field('description', $post->ID); ?> </p>

                                 <a class="dedcription-btn pop recrut" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                     <span class="name-descripeion">En savoir plus</span>
                                     <div class="btn-icon">
                                         <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                     </div>
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>


                    <?php
                    } else {
                        $counter++; 
                        if (!$parent_included) {
                           echo '<div id="parentId">';
                         
                           $parent_included = true;
                        }
                        
                ?>
                <div class="col-lg-16 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" class="content">
                         <?php
                            if ($counter <= 2) {
                                echo ("<div class='card recrutements'>");
                            } else {
                                echo ("<div class='card recrutements hide-block'  id='$cat'>");
                                //var_dump($cat); data-id='$cat'
                            }
                            ?>
                         <div class="card-header">
                             <div>
                                 <img src=<?php echo $img["url"]; ?> class='mymap-icon' alt=''>

                             </div>
                             <div>
                                 <span>
                                     <div><?php echo '<p>' . $custom_term->name . '</p>'; ?>
                                     </div>

                                     <div> <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>

                                     <div class="bnt-maker "><?php the_field('nom', $post->ID); ?>
                                     </div>

                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <p><?php the_field('description', $post->ID); ?> </p>

                             <a class="dedcription-btn pop recrut" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                 <span class="name-descripeion">En savoir plus</span>
                                 <div class="btn-icon">
                                     <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                 </div>
                             </a>
                         </div>
                        </div>
 </div>


 <?php
                    }
                endwhile;
                echo('</div>');
            }
           
            if ($custom_term->count > 2) {
               
                echo ("<div class='show-more' data-id='$current_category'>Show more</div>");
                

            }
        }
    ?>



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

               var tax = ["89","93"];


                $(".show-more").click(function(){
                var ids = $(this).attr("data-id");
                $("#"+ids).css({"display": "block"});
               

                for(let i = 0; i < tax.length; i ++){

                    if(tax[i] != ids){
                    $("#"+tax[i]).css({"display": "none"});
                    }
                
                
                }
                
        });



});

   </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you expect to happen when you click the "show more" button?

Comment: Initially, for each category only two elements appear, when I click on the display more button, the other elements are displayed.With this code , only one is displayed but I have 4 posts  should be displayed

Comment: Could you please update your question to include a sample of your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I made a function for getting the index from a DOM element from a set of elements of the same class. I wasn't quite sure what you were doing with the `data-id` attribute so I left it alone.

```
function get_index(list,item){
    for (l in list)
  {
    if(list[l] === item){
        return l;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".show-more").click(function(){   
    let index = get_index($(".show-more"),this);
  console.log(index);
 });
});
```

Comment: With data-id , I want to pass the id of category , because when click on show more in each category we should close the button show more is last opened

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.show-block').toggleClass('show-block hide-block').toggle();
$(this).prev().find('.hide-block').toggleClass('hide-block show-block').toggle();
```

Comment: The same result , only the first index is displayed

Comment: You create div only when $custom_term->name != "Adventure".  Are you sure you have more posts NOT Adventure?  Right-click on Show more and select "Inspect" to see how many posts have "hide-block" in DOM.

Comment: The div bloqued only for category who have more than 2 posts .In click show more only the first post is displayed like in inspect picture I added

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtiGE.png

Comment: When you click "Show More", where did it get class name = "less"?  I don't see how this happens in your $(".show-more").click() function.  Maybe different function is doing something?

Comment: It is a code I added to execute after show more click , when click show less return to initial display

Comment: $(this).text() === 'show more' ? $(this).text('Show less').addClass('less') : $(this).text('show more');

Comment: I'm sorry.  I don't know why it doesn't work.  It looks good.  The last suggestion I have is try this: $('.hide-block').toggleClass('hide-block show-block').css({"display": "block", visibility:'visible'});  If it doesn't work, then another function somewhere is hiding it again

Comment: Thank you very much .It works , but when I click in show more for some category , all category with button show more are opened . It should only the current category clicked opened

Comment: $(this).prev().find('.hide-block').toggleClass('hide-block show-block').css({"display": "block", visibility:'visible'});

Comment: thank you , it works , but other problem , when I click in show more for current category , the last show more opened should be closed .Only show more for current is opened

Comment: Then hide first : $('.show-block').toggleClass('show-block hide-block').toggle(); $(this).prev().find('.hide-block').toggleClass('hide-block show-block').toggle();

Comment: It works , thank you .How I can display show more by slice for example in every click show more display 2 posts

Comment: That would be a lot more complicated with the current architecture.  For instance, you need both Show More and Show Less after Show More is clicked. There are many ways to do this, but everything will look very different than now... and it's too much to post here.

Comment: for button show less I added this code

Comment: $(this).text() === 'show more' ? $(this).text('Show less').addClass('less') : $(this).text('show more');

Comment: $(".less").click(function(){
                    $('.show-block').toggleClass('show-block hide-block').toggle(); 

                });

Comment: I have problem , if I click show more , then show less , it works .Now I click show more for new , it not worked